# load failed UWP.csproj : error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

My Xamarin.UWP suddenly won't load after Visual Studio 2017 15.4.

I did update my Xamarin PCL and others. But the UWP Project will not load anymore. I can't get to it?

I get this in my VS IDE Output;

`UWP.csproj : error  : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

How would I og about solving this?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and it turned out that the error was caused by not having all the assets for UWP projects, so I made sure the projects has all assets added to UWP.csproj fil and assets folder.

So my ItemGroup looks like this

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Properties\Default.rd.xml" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LockScreenLogo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LockScreenLogo.scale-125.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LockScreenLogo.scale-150.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LockScreenLogo.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-125.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-150.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-125.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-150.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-125.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-150.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-16_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-32_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-48_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-256_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\StoreLogo.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-125.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-150.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-400.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out on my search.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue while after upgrading from vs2015 to vs2017.

After following this 
[link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/128532/project-load-failed.html)
and replacing the platform target, it loaded again.

(yes, I know, it doesn't seem to make any sense)

---

- Right click target UWP project and select "edit"
- Alter find and change keys to these values:

replacement:

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.16299.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10586.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

Note: the project's platform target might get disrupted.

Comment: Same situation with same versions of VisualStudio & Windows 10.  This solution is what fixed it for me too.